# What is purpose of -lrt option?

Tags: c++, g++, posix, message-queue

Why `-lrt` option is used while compiling message queue code?Is rt is for real time library?

```
g++ messageq.cpp -lrt
```

Comment: please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754032/what-library-does-ld-option-lrt-refer-to-bionic-libc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To link-in `librt.a` or `librt.so`, which is the Realtime Extensions library.