# math library and POSIX realtime extensions for Mac

Tags: macos, clang, ld, cc

Although more a novice I try to explain my problem.
I am on a Mac and use command line to build the executable. The compiling command works successfully on Ubuntu.

```
cc   program.o file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o -lm -lrt -o program
ld: library not found for -lrt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

If I run with -v command I get the following:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -o program program.o file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o -lm -lrt -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: library not found for -lrt
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any hint?

I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663097/gcc-lm-lz-lrt-options-what-are-they-about) what *-lm -lrt* mean but still could not figure out a solution.

**Update 1:** According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754032/what-library-does-ld-option-lrt-refer-to-bionic-libc) *-lrt* is not available for Mac.

**Update 2:** I have found two possible solutions: (a) either to remove completely the flag or (b) use the *-lSystem.B* instead. The real-time extensions seems to be in libSystem.B.dylib as explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905193454/http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2008/Oct/msg00001.html).

Comment: Error is `ld: library not found for -lrt`. This means that the linker (`ld`) couldn't find the library providing POSIX realtime extensions. Either it is not installed or you should provide its path with `-L` option.

Comment: @ mouviciel According to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754032/what-library-does-ld-option-lrt-refer-to-bionic-libc) *-lrt* is not available for Mac

Comment: I guess in the end I answered to my own question. Thus, I updated with two possible solutions.

Comment: You can answer your own question. If one of the solutions you found works, this would help other people with the same problem.